# How to make a 3D graph from a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, graph, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python (developing on Jupyter Notebook).
I am trying to read from a CSV that has several columns, three of which need to be charted into a wire frame (3D). The CSV contains some 5k rows.

The columns in the CSD are a date (text in `dd/mm/yy` format) and 2 longs (decimal format).

Is there sample code you can share please?
The main bit is the conversion of the text date to something that is plottable.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
data = pd.read_csv('my.csv')
ax1.scatter3D(data['DATE'], data['average'], data['top-height'])
plt.show()

Comment: However, the above results in an error as the date cannot be converted from a string to a float.

Comment: Can anyone help please?